# How to configure mailjet and laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, smtp, mailjet

I'm trying to use Mailjet to send the mails from my website which is using Laravel.

I've tried to modify the file app/config/mail.php and set the configurations that have been given by mailjet but this is not working. Is there something else to do ?

I have verified the domain from where I'm sending the mails in mailjet but still nothing.

Did anyone faced the same issue ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is not working exactly ? Do you get an exception ?

Comment: Could you please share your setup, but mask the passwords and logins.

Comment: I have installed Laravel Mailjet in order to send emails.

I am currently using "Sendgrid"

I am trying my laravel system to use "Laravel Mailjet" as email provider so emails will be sent through it

I am not sure which file i need to change or update service to use Mailjet as Mail driver instead of sendgrid

Any thoughts or help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that mailjet had not yet accepted the mail address I was sending mail with.

Problem is solved.

Comment: I have installed Laravel Mailjet in order to send emails.

I am currently using "Sendgrid"

I am trying my laravel system to use "Laravel Mailjet" as email provider so emails will be sent through it

I am not sure which file i need to change or update service to use Mailjet as Mail driver instead of sendgrid

Any thoughts or help is appreciated